# Cypher Query Regex To Select Vertex and Edge

Tags: javascript, regex, cypher, lex

I am trying to parse Cypher query with match condition to extract its vertex, connecting edges and return condition. It can have two more regex to find pattern. What could be Regex1 and Regex2:

```
MATCH (A)-[E1]->(B), (A)-[E2]->(C), (B)-[E3]->(C)
WHERE E1.TYPE = ''marriedTo'' AND C.NAME = ''Ares''
RETURN A.NAME AS PARENT1_NAME, B.NAME AS PARENT2_NAME
```

Regex1 Output = `['(A)-[E1]->(B)','(A)-[E2]->(C)','(B)-[E3]->(C)']`

Regex2 Output = `[E1.TYPE = "marriedTo" , 'C.NAME = "Ares"]`

```
MATCH (a)
RETURN a.NAME AS name
ORDER BY a.NAME ASC
```

Regex1 Output = `['(a)']`

Regex2 Output = `[]`

```
MATCH (a), (A)
RETURN a.NAME AS name
```

Regex1 Output = `['(a)','(A)']`

Regex2 Output = `[]`

```
MATCH (a)-[e]-(b)
RETURN e.TYPE AS type
ORDER BY e.TYPE ASC
```

Regex1 Output = `['(a)-[e]-(b)']`

Regex2 Output = `[]`

```
MATCH (A)-[E1]->(B), (B)-[E2]->(C)
WHERE A.NAME = 'Zeus'
RETURN A.NAME as ANAME, B.NAME AS BNAME, C.NAME AS CNAME
ORDER BY B.NAME ASC, C.NAME ASC
```

Regex1 Output = `['(A)-[E1]->(B)','(B)-[E2]->(C)']`

Regex2 Output = `[A.NAME = 'Zeus']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For javascript version look at the end of the post**

`(?<=MATCH)(?:(?:.*?=)?\s+(.+?)\s+)(?=WHERE|RETURN)(?:WHERE\s+(.+?)\s+(?=RETURN))?`

See the regex working at https://regex101.com/r/aWo08j/1/

Sorry I used python flavour for the regex string. Please escape all the `\` while using in java.

It should return two groups one for MATCH clause and the second group for WHERE clause. So you get both the sections with one regex.

Explanation below;-

**For Match condition**

```
(?<=MATCH)   //positive look behind match only that appears after this
(?:          //Non capturing group START match this but do not capture
(?:.*?=)     //Do not capture till first equal to sign in match.
\s+          //Match any spaces
(.+?)         //Match and CAPTURE our match condition
\s+         //Match any spaces
)           //Non capturing group END
(?=WHERE|RETURN) //Positive lookahead match only if followed by WHERE or RETURN
```

**For Where Edges**

```
(?:        //Non capturing group START
WHERE      //Match WHERE but do not capture
\s+        //Match space after WHERE but do not capture
(.+?)       //This is our where clause MATCH and CAPTURE!
\s+        //Match space after where clause but do not capture
(?=RETURN) //Positive Lookahead capture only if followed by RETURN
)          //Non capturing group END
?          //The whole WHERE clause may or may not occur.
```

A java version running is here https://repl.it/LR5s/11

EDITED THE REGEX TO MATCH OP's REQUEST AND ADDED JS VERSION HERE

---

**Java Script Version**

```
/(?:^MATCH(?:.*?=)?\s+(.+?)\s+)(?=WHERE|RETURN)(?:WHERE\s+(.+?)\s+(?=RETURN))?/img
```

Now the solution is the same except two differences due to the fact that javascript doesn't allow look-behind. Difference are explained below:-

```
/regex-expression/options //This is the format for javascript regular expression
^                         //Beginning of a line
MATCH                     //MATCH is now brought inside the non capturing group as there is no lookbehind in js
/img                      //options i-case insensitive; m-multiline; g-global don't stop after first match
```

Rest of the regular expression remains the same. Like before we have two groups that will give back our `match` vertices and `where` edges.

The sample js for this is https://repl.it/LTis/1.

Comment: MATCH p = (a)-[*1..2]->(b)
WHERE a.NAME = 'Chaos'
RETURN b.NAME AS Name
ORDER BY b.NAME

Comment: In above case its selecting p also , how to avoid this

Comment: I am getting while using JavaScript ? positive look behind match giving problem @bulbus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154811/discussion-between-sumeet-and-bulbus).